# Let f(x),g(x) be complex polynomials, if f(x) | g(x) and g(x) | f(x) then..

Tags: polynomials

Let $f(x), g(x)$ be complex polynomials. If $f(x) | g(x)$ and $g(x) | f(x)$ then there exists a non-zero complex number $a$ such that $f(x) = ag(x)$.

Im not sure if what I did is correct;

I said if $f(x) | g(x)$ and $g(x) | f(x)$, then both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are non-zero polynomials

So by the division algorithm for polynomials, $f(x) = q1(x)g(x)$ where polynomial $q_1(x)$ does not equal zero.

And also, $g(x) = q_2(x)f(x)$ where $q_2(x)$ does not equal zero.

This means, $f(x) = q_2(x)q_1(x)g(x)$, so $q_2(x)q_1(x) = a$ (complex)

I don't think this is sufficient...

Comment: you mean that $f(x)=q_1(x)q_2(x)f(x)$ right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful: I think you meant to write $f(x) = q_2(x)q_1(x)\underline{\underline{f(x)}}$. Now consider the degree of both of these polynomials; what is $\deg q_1$? Why is $q_1(x)$ non-zero?

(There is also a stupid case to deal with when $f(x) = g(x) = 0$, and you have a choice of $q_1$ and $q_2$. Choose wisely.)

Comment: Zero does not divide zero so $f(x)=g(x)=0$ can't happen.

Comment: @MattSamuel Depends on your definition of "divides", surely? In a commutative ring (here $\mathbb{C}[x]$) the natural definition seems to me to be "$g|h$ iff there exists $f\neq 0$ with $fg = h$". If you want to make an exception for $0$ somewhere, go ahead, but definitions vary from author to author, so a discussion of which is correct doesn't seem all that useful. I just flagged it up as a potential issue.

Comment: hey, thanks, I think i see what you mean, since f(x) = q2(x)q1(x)f(x), both sides have to have the same degree, so q2(x)q1(x) cannot have an x term in it (i.e. they have x^0), so q2(x)q1(x) has to be a complex number!

Comment: No reason to require the factor $\neq 0$ in the definition of divisibility. In a (commutative) ring $R$,  $a\mid b \iff (\exists c\in R)(c\cdot a = b)$ is a perfectly fine definition of divisibility.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $f=h_1g$, $g=h_2f$ and $deg(qp)=deg(q)+deg(p)$ provided $p$ and $q$ are non-zero.

Comment: If you work with $\deg 0 = -\infty$, the formula holds also for $p = 0$ or $q = 0$.

Comment: That's interesting, I had never seen deg$0$ defined as $-\infty$.